# How to set xdvi options in auctex

Tags: auctex

I use xdvi and auctex with

```
;;; 1
(setq tex-dvi-view-command "xdvi -editor 'emacsclient -a emacs --no-wait +%l %f'")
```

All works fine. Now I want xdvi to use the options -s 6 -geometry 917X736. First I tried

```
;;; 2
(setq tex-dvi-view-command "xdvi -s 6 -geometry 917X736 -editor 'emacsclient -a emacs --no-wait +%l %f'")
```

That doesn't work. Next I tried

```
;;; 3
(setq xdvi-program "xdvi -s 6 -geometry 917X736")
```

which also doesn't work. What does work is to remove 1 and use

```
;;; 4
(setq TeX-view-program-selection
  '((output-dvi "DVI Viewer")))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
  '(("DVI Viewer" "xdvi -geometry 917X736 -s 6 %o")))
```

which unfortunately looses the search forward via emacsclient. Does anyone know how to set the xdvi zoom and geometry options in 1, or to set the emacsclient in 4? I would be happy to use either solution. I'm using emacs-24.4 and AUCTeX 11.88. Thanks.

Comment: `tex-dvi-dview-command` is not part of AUCTeX, but of the vanilla TeX mode of Emacs.  For AUCTeX, try adding `" -sourceposition \"%n %b\" -editor \"%cS\""` without quotes in your `DVI Viewer` specification.

Comment: Thanks. "DVI Viewer" "xdvi -sourceposition \"%n %b\" -editor \"%cS\" -geometry 917X736 -s 6 %o" is what I want. Also works with emacs-25.0.50.1 if anyone is using the devel version.

Answer (score 1):

AUCTeX supports by default forward/inverse search with xdvi, you can see the options used for that in the value of the variable `TeX-view-program-list-builtin`.  This variable is not customizable, but you have (at least) two options:

1. `setq` the variable in your init file copying the default value and add there the flags `-geometry 917X736 -s 6`
2. define a new viewer in `TeX-view-program-list`, as you suggested in your question, and add there the options to enable forward/inverse search: `-sourceposition \"%n %b\" -editor \"%cS\"`